# JavaScript Empty String Check Efficiency

Tags: javascript, coding-efficiency

I was on this page about [calculating Levenshtein distances](https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927) and the poster checked for empty strings with

```
a.length == 0
```

A commenter, in his code, did so with

```
!a.length
```

And my immediate thought was to use

```
!a
```

For readability the first option is, at least in my opinion, the best. I was wondering what the efficiency differences are

I'd also be interested to know how to find out the efficiency differences between operations in general so if I could get some sources for that as well that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In general, `!a` is not equal to the other cases.

Comment: Performance differences, if any, would be negligible, so it's basically a matter of personal preference, to which I second the `s.length === 0` option.